# How to deal with 5 or 6 digit values for Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geolocation

I am trying to read in a dataframe and the latitude and longitude doesn't seem accurate. And this is not only for few rows but an entire dataframe with more than 100k rows.

[screenshot of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7xK5.png)

How do you handle such data?

Comment: What does the original data look like before you read it?

Comment: Exactly like what you see here. I have made no modification to the lat and long column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your source could be using 99999 instead of NaN. I'd replace these with NaN (missing):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 99999.0], [2, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df[['B']] = df[['B']].replace(99999., np.nan)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   A    B
0  1  NaN
1  2  4.0
```

i.e.

```
df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']] = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].replace(99999., np.nan)
```

*Note: This might replace some geo locations that are legitimately 99999 but that's very unlikely!*

Comment: But its not only the ones with 999999, if you see the rows there is one with 6439997. smth. Is it a value, if so how do you get that to coordinates.